# What is exactly happening to DEUS

Tags: defi

https://cointelegraph.com/news/deus-finance-exploit-hackers-get-away-with-3m-worth-of-dai-and-ether

And what does this do

[image]

I know that AMM means automated market maker.

So someone dump DEI in the maker and then what. Dump DEI to reduce price. Knowing that the price is used by some algorithm do something else?

Comment: Peckshield did an analysis in their twitter account https://twitter.com/peckshield/status/1503632734299701250

Comment: That is still unclear. So there is an AMM. WHere is the AMM? In what website?

Comment: The AMM is a PancakeSwap DEI-USDC pair.

Comment: Ah. It's not even clearly stated in the twitter. How do you get that?